# How to use Homebrew to package code directories and scripts?

Tags: bash, github, package, homebrew

I have this [Code repo](https://github.com/Stack-Box/StackBox) that I want to package using Homebrew. I want to tap to the Github repo and run an install to pull the contents. And later, something like `stackbox run` should use the [starter script](https://github.com/Stack-Box/StackBox/blob/master/stack_box.sh) to run the package.

I'm also open to other ways of packaging. I'm aware we can package separate languages using their respective package managers like pip or npm. But, I want the whole codebase here to build and run docker containers - which is the use case I'm solving for.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you seen Homebrew’s documentation? https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the following formula to package with src and run docker containers.

```
class Stackbox < Formula
  desc "Create app stacks loaded with all your favourite clients, services and infra along with code boilerplates in under 5 mins."
  homepage ""
  url "https://github.com/Stack-Box/StackBox/archive/v1.2.0.tar.gz"
  sha256 "ea9bcc6905169868ac4f5ee54b7ace6ad8ed8416d482accbcf3fb7211027436b"

  depends_on "docker"
  depends_on "docker-compose"
  depends_on "python"
  depends_on "shc"

  def install
    system "mkdir -p /usr/local/Cellar/stackbox/1.2.0/bin"
    system "cp -a . /usr/local/Cellar/stackbox/1.2.0/"
    system "shc -f ./brew/stackbox-brew.sh -o stackbox"
    system "cp ./stackbox /usr/local/Cellar/stackbox/1.2.0/bin/"
  end
end
```